# FlutterFire cli - how to switch between separate firebase consoles

Tags: firebase, flutter

I have two separate firebase consoles accessed from two separate google accounts.

- Firebase console "A" has three projects. Google account a@gmail.com
- Firebase console "B" has one project. Google account b@gmail.com

Originally, I set up the Firebase "A" console using flutterfire cli `flutterfire configure` and it worked just fine, but setting up "B", it seems like there is some kind of caching for "A" issue.

In my completely separate google account for firebase console "B" I have created a project that I now need to run `flutterfire configure` for in the separate directory for project "B".

Using `firebase login:add a@gmail.com` and `firebase login:add b@gmail.com`. Both accounts have been authed, no problem. So I should be able to use `firebase login:use` to switch between the two, however `flutterfire configure` and `firebase projects:list` do not seem to respect which firebase account I'm signed into. They only show the projects for "A", never "B".

For example, switching to the directory for firebase project "B", I run `firebase login:use b@gmail.com` and then `flutterfire configure --account=b@gmail.com`. `flutterfire configure`, incorrectly, the 3 projects from "A". Running `firebase projects:list` in directory "B" after running `firebase login:use b@gmail.com`, only shows the projects from "A", not the 1 project I'm expecting to see from project "B".

In the directory for project "B", I tried running `firebase init` and it correctly listed my 1 project for "B" and I was able to init. But immediately after the init, running `flutterfire configure` or `flutterfire configure --account=b@gmail.com`, in the directory for "B", the following exception is returned, stating it can't find project "B" in the firebase account for "A". Notice that it states it "Found 3 Firebase projects", but project "B" only has 1 project, "A" has 3 projects.

```
i Found 3 Firebase projects. Selecting project B.
FirebaseProjectNotFoundException: Firebase project id "B" could not be found on this Firebase account.
```

And I am signed into to "B", not "A". Some kind of cache issue? How do I break the cache?

I have completely removed `npm -g firebase-tools` and `flutterfire` from dart global. I've deleted all .firebaserc and firebase.json files I could find. None of it worked.

## ANSWER (for my use case):

If you're having issues switching accounts `firebase projects:list --debug` may very well give you the insight for more difficult issues like mine here.

Using `firebase projects:list --debug` I saw that the authorization was using an ENV `FIREBASE_TOKEN`, which at some point I must have put into my `~/.bashrc`. This token was for project "A". I removed the ENV token and now everything is working as expected.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, changing FIREBASE_TOKEN to another account's token also helped me. Maybe it's worth making an answer in "Answers" section and approving it so that people can find it easier?

Answer (score 30):

I had the same scenario. What worked for me was the following:

Add the A account in the possible accounts to use.

```
firebase login:add a@gmail.com
```

Configure project selection with correct account.

```
flutterfire configure --account a@gmail.com
```

Comment: From directory for "b" login:add was successful for gmail "b". However, from directory "b" configure --account b@gmail.com still shows only projects for google account "a". Also, did the same for "a", which already existed, as you suggested, but I cannot get "b" projects to display in the "b" directory. Maddening. I also tried signing out of both google accounts firebase logout a@gmail.com and b@gmail.com and reauthing, but to no avail.

Comment: mainly account will authorize the --account , i got permission denied . did u know why still on use main account ? instead of other / available ?

Answer (score 15):

Step 1: See all available accounts

```
 firebase login:list
```

Step 2: Add more accounts:

```
firebase login:add email@email.com
```

Step 3: Switch to another email

```
firebase login:list  (to see if email was successfully added)
firebase login:use whateverEmail@email.com (to switch email)
```

Step 4 :

```
flutterfire configure --account whateverEmail@email.com
```

Comment: I have tried all of this, but it only shows projects from 1 account. I cannot change accounts, even though I'm not signed in to account "a". It is maddening that I can't simply change the account I want to configure.

Comment: Error: Could not determine active Firebase project directory

Comment: Upon login:use I also get: "Error: Could not determine active Firebase project directory" which prevents to use the other user